# Business Central API | Find $Expand property name

Tags: odata, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-business-central

Let's say I wanted to retrieve the sales headers along with their lines, I would use the following URL:
[https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/v2.0/{GUID}/Sandbox/ODataV4/Company('{CompanyName}')/SalesInvoice?$expand=SalesInvoiceSalesLines](https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/v2.0/%7BGUID%7D/Sandbox/ODataV4/Company(%27%7BCompanyName%7D%27)/SalesInvoice?$expand=SalesInvoiceSalesLines)

And if I wanted to retrieve the Purchase Invoice, I would use this one:

[https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/v2.0/{GUID}/Sandbox/ODataV4/Company('{CompanyName}')/PurchaseInvoice?$expand=PurchaseInvoicePurchLines](https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/v2.0/%7BGUID%7D/Sandbox/ODataV4/Company(%27%7BCompanyName%7D%27)/PurchaseInvoice?$expand=PurchaseInvoicePurchLines)

So, for the sales, the expand property has the value **SalesInvoiceSalesLines** while for the purchases, the value is **PurchaseInvoicePurchLines**.

Is there some logic or a documentation that can help me find what the expand property's value needs to be if I want to expand, say, the SalesCreditMemo lines ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to deduct that from the metadata of the endpoint in question e.g.:

[https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/v2.0/{GUID}/Sandbox/ODataV4/$metadata#Company('{CompanyName}')/SalesCreditMemo](https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/v2.0/%7BGUID%7D/Sandbox/ODataV4/$metadata#Company(%27%7BCompanyName%7D%27)/SalesCreditMemo)

Then search for "Line" in the the returned XML document.